# Set background of parent based on Content Control's content

Tags: wpf, styles

I have this tabitem (default style) template where the tab item's background is set to a fixed colour.

```
<Style x:Key="tbitem" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="Continue"/>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation" Value="Continue"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="0" Margin="0" Background="Transparent" >
                        <DockPanel>
                            <Label   x:Name="TabLabel" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Foreground="White" FontWeight="ExtraBold" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="14" >
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  x:Name="ContentSite" RecognizesAccessKey="True" ContentSource="Header" />
                            </Label>
                            <Button Name="PART_BTNCLOSE" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Style="{StaticResource CloseButtonStyle}" Command="USD:ActionCommands.CloseSessionTab"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Margin" Value="2,0,0,0"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_BTNCLOSE" Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding CloseButtonVisibility}"/>
                            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="Continue"/>
                            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation" Value="Continue"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="TabLabel" Property="Foreground" Value="#666666"/>
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And my actual tabitem contains a textblock to display the tab header

```
<TabItem Style="{StaticResource SessionTabs}" >
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="Tab 1"  >

                    </TextBlock>

                </TabItem.Header>

            </TabItem>
```

All working good so far. The problem is.. yet times I have to change one of my tab colour based on some conditions and that If I'm doing it to my textblock then the look and feel is quite odd.
[image]

Is there any way I can set my parent's border background to match my textblock's background? or somehow trigger/update ancestor's background from the child?

Comment: sorry.. don't bother abt the difference in style names.. both tbItems & sessiontabs are identical.

Comment: Is your `TextBlock` static or you are changing the background from the code-behind? If you are changing from code behind that along with `TextBlock` you can update `TabItem` background as well. Best Approach is to bind Background of both control to some property with `TwoWay` binding.

Comment: well... unfortunately I can't use code behind because of some unavoidable situations... will there be any option available w/o code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Label padding to 0 and change TabItemHeader like so:

```
<TabItem.Header>
   <Grid Background="Red" Margin="0 0 -10 0">
      <TextBlock Margin="5 5 15 5" Text="Tab 1"/>
   </Grid>
</TabItem.Header>
```

-10 is your button width and 15 is (5 + button.Width)

Comment: But I can only set the background to my textblock .. not really to the tab :(

Comment: can you change code and set Grid as parent of your textblock? if you can do that then you can set Grid background

Comment: Ok, I can do that. I can wrap my Textblock with a grid, but will that occupy the whole label and remove the odd look?

Comment: No sorry, I have edit the answer. Just set Label padding to 0 and textblock padding to 5

Comment: yeap, that solved the problem of having the textblock all over the label.. but if you see my screenshot, I have an X as well on the tab to close it which also falls under the same border. now my X has a different color and all other portion of tab has different colour :) I blv setting the background color only the option for me..

Comment: OK, I see please try this one (I have edited answer)

Comment: That seem's perfect @llya Grigoyan. I just need to play change it -17 instead of -10 so that it fits perfectly. Thank you so much..